# Firebase wildcard redirect to a variable

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to have a user browse to a url such as:
www.example.com/12345

and have "12345" available in a variable within index.html?

I want to be able to use this value in a db lookup.

I have read about wildcard redirects but just can't get it working:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do.  Please edit the question to show what you tried that isn't working the way you expect, both configuration and javascript code.

Comment: Seems  to me like a routing question not related to firebase